# How to calculate desired radius or distance with specific latitude and longitude in MYSQL with proper SQL standard?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know about how to calculate desired radius or distance with specific latitude and longitude in MYSQL with proper SQL standard?
I have found many solutions on internet but they are taking to much time they have cos and other terms involved.please help!

Comment: For this you need to rely on sql query and because it involves rich calculation that's why it's taking some time may be on live server it will run fast have a try.

Comment: can suggest me any example query. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: How accurate do you need your answer to be? It is possible to speed up the calculation, by sacrificing the exactness of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look this link.This may help you.

[Calculate Distance.](http://www.marketingtechblog.com/calculate-distance/)

Answer (score 4):

To calculate the distance between two GPS points I'm using a MySQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `distance`(lat1 FLOAT(10,7), lng1 FLOAT(10,7), lat2 FLOAT(10,7), lng2 FLOAT(10,7)) RETURNS FLOAT(20,2)
    RETURN ROUND(6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((lat1 -ABS( lat2 )) * PI()/180 / 2),2) + COS(lat1 * PI()/180 ) * COS( ABS ( lat2 ) *  PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((lng1 - lng2) *  PI()/180 / 2), 2) )), 2);
```

and then it's pretty easy to use it:

```
SELECT
    distance( city1.latitude, city1.longtitude, city2.latitude, city2.longtitude) AS distanceKM
FROM
    city1, city2 ...
```

You can [read here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) how the cordinates to kilometers are being converted

**Note:** `6371` is the [Earth radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) in kilometers so if you need to the distance in miles you will have to replace it with `3959`